# How to show branch coverage for C++ project on coveralls.io?

Tags: code-coverage, coveralls

I am using the coveralls.io service to display line coverage for my C++ project. I also want to track branch coverage, but cannot get it to work.

On Travis CI, I use this call to generate the coverage report:

`coveralls -r <my_project_root> -b <my_build_dir> --verbose --gcov=gcov --gcov-options '\-lpbc';`

The coveralls script is previously installed with `pip`

`pip install cpp-coveralls urllib3[secure]`

I get the line coverage shown correctly on coveralls.io, but not the branch coverage. I don't know what of the following things I am doing wrong.

- Do I have to activate it on coveralls.io explicitly?
- Is there something wrong with the `coveralls` command?
- Can `coveralls.io` even show branch coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty late to the party, but to answer your question(s):

Yes, you will want to enable the Coveralls setting for BRANCH COVERAGE: INCLUDE IN AGGREGATE %:

[image: coveralls setting - branch coverage]

Of course, this will only work if branch coverage is included in your original coverage report.

That happens in a prior step, when you compile the original project into an "instrumented" version of the source code and generate the GCOV coverage report, *before* you use the `coveralls` command to POST the coverage report to Coveralls.

Something like:

```
    gcc -Wall -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs cov.c
    gcov --branch-probabilities cov.c
```

*Source: [gcov Wiki - Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcov#Example)*